# Backbone JS - event problems adding multiple Views into same parent container

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

My code fetches a Collection from the server and iterates through it. For each model fetched it creates a View that is appended to the same parent element. Each of these views has a "click" event that triggers a function.

The problem is that clicking on any item in the list causes the event function to trigger for ALL elements in the list. The only workaround I have is to make the function itself dynamic and try to determine if it should run based on things like the ID of the item clicked:

```
    'click .request_box': function(e) {
      var myid = $(e.currentTarget).attr("id");
        // code here which determines whether the function runs
      }
    }
```

This is a workaround, but it is also a hack, and I'm sure there has to be a better way of dealing with what must be a common problem (creating a list). Repeat searching around the web does not suggest any better way, so I am posting in the hope someone with more experience using Backbone can offer suggestions on a better way to approach this problem....

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @trevelyan Without some more information it's hard to say for sure what your issue is, but I'm guessing that your click event is probably not declared in your *child* views but rather in your collection's view.